# How do I port this simple htaccess rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, modx

I have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On                             
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f            #do not process for real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d            #do not process for real folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]      #rewrite
```

I have tried to add this to my nginx conf file

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

inside my

```
server{...}
```

block with limited success, I get

http://example.com/about/contact.html > /index.php?q=/about/contact.html

instead of

http://example.com/about/contact.html > /index.php?q=about/contact.html

and, while minor, this leading / is breaking MODx. (even when hacking to modify the value of `$_GET['q']`, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

[yes, I have restarted nginx]

Answer (score 1):

> MODx

MODx have a manual page with a sample nginx conf file which works for me; http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Nginx+Server+Config